# Perform a segue from a UITableView to a new view controller Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin.iOS application which includes a Navigation Controller where the root in a View Controller `ViewController.cs`, inside the UIViewController (the default one created in a single view application) is a Table View which has a segue to a new View Controller.

Depicted in Storyboard below.

[image: ViewControllers]

The Table view is controlled by the `StationsTableViewSource.cs` code which inherits from `UITableViewSource`. The source for the Table View is set inside the `ViewController.cs`.

```
StationsTable.Source = new StationsTableViewSource(StationPlayer.StationsTitleList)
```

When I press a cell in the table view I want to segue to the new view controller but as I see it:

1. I have no access to the Parent/Root/Containing View Controller from the Table View
2. I have no access to the New View Controller from the Table View.

My question is this, with a set up as above, how can I perform a segue from a cell inside a tableview nested in a View Controller to another View Controller?

Please correct the terminology - not too hot on Xamarin/iOS lingo.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, we need to figure out which segue have you created?

### 1.From your tableViewCell to a new ViewController.

This means: tap down on the `Cell` + ctrl and drag to a new ViewContoller. In this way, there's no need to execute `PerformSegue()` manually. When you click the Cell, it will push to a new Controller.

### 2.From your ViewContoller to a new ViewController

This means: tap down on the bottom bar of the ViewContoller + ctrl and drag to a new ViewController. In this way, we need to click the segue we created above then set the `Identifier`. When we click the Cell, the event below will be triggered:

```
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    //use this method we can push to a new viewController
    //the first parameter is the identifier we set above
    parentVC.PerformSegue("NewPush", indexPath);
}
```

> I have no access to the Parent/Root/Containing View Controller from
>   the Table View

When you construct this Source you can pass your "Parent" ViewController like:

```
ViewController parentVC;
//You can add other parameters you want in this initial method
public MyTableViewCellSource(ViewController viewController, ...)
{
    parentVC = viewController;
}
```

Moreover both segues will fire `PrepareForSegue()` in the parent ViewController. In this method you can pass parameters to the new ViewController:

```
public override void PrepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
{
    if (segue.Identifier == "NewPush")
    {
        SecondVC secondVC = segue.DestinationViewController as SecondVC;
        ...//do some configuration
    }
}
```

About how to use segue, you can read [this official documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/storyboards/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks @land-lu-msft - just a quick follow-up. Using method 1. above I should be able to click on any cell/row in the table view and segue to the new view controller with no more code? Method 1 will still fire the PrepareForSegue method and then segue so why choose to use Method 2. and pass a reference to the Source ViewController object? - Which would you consider best practice?

Comment: These are two ways using segue. There's no best about it, all is depending on your choice. The second method can be more flexible. Assume a scenario that if we also want to push to the same VC using a button, we can also use this segue instead of creating a new one. The only difference is the segue's sender(who triggers it). Moreover about pushing, we can also use code, it's all depending on you.

Comment: This works great! What's the best way to pass the selected cell's data to the new control on the segue? Say the the table cell is showing an ListItem object. How would I pass the correct ListItem object to the new controller (say for a detailed view)?